# Openedge Equivalent of SQL Server's outer apply

Tags: openedge, progress-db

I have two tables I need to "join" together.

Employment Table

```
 First      Middle     Last       ID
-------    -------   -------    ------
 John       Manly      Doe        12345
```

Job Responsibilities

```
ID        fkEmploymentID          Title         Main Role
---          ----                 -----              -----
1           12345                Worker bee         True
2           12345                Honey Sucker       False
```

So if I do a typical join, I'd get two records.  I only want one record with the main role (true).

Normally in SQL Server I'd do an `Outer apply` / select to take the record I want.  However, this doesn't seem to be supported on Openedge.

This is OpenEdge 11.1.

Comment: `outer apply` is Microsoft's non-standard version of a lateral join. Maybe Progress supports the standard `left join lateral`?

Comment: Yes, LEFT JOIN is supported by Progress

Comment: looks like left lateral join is almost identical to outer apply.  However, it doesn't appear to be compatible with 11.1...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this progress query should do it, but let me know if I understood the question wrong.

```
for each Job no-lock where Job.mainRole = True,
    each Emp no-lock where Emp.ID = Job.fkEmploymentID:

  disp Emp.First Emp.Middle Emp.Last Emp.ID Job.Title Job.mainRole

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what OUTER APPLY does. But, the following query gets you what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (FIRST VARCHAR(10), MIDDLE VARCHAR(10), LAST VARCHAR(10), ID INT);

INSERT INTO EMP VALUES ('JOHN', 'MANLY', 'DOE', 12345);

CREATE TABLE JOB (ID INT, EMPID INT, TITLE VARCHAR(20), MAIN_ROLE BIT);

INSERT INTO JOB VALUES (1, 12345, 'WORKER BEE', 0);
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES (1, 12345, 'HONEY SUCKER', 1);

SELECT EMP.FIRST, EMP.ID, JOB.TITLE FROM EMP INNER JOIN JOB ON EMP.ID = JOB.EMPID WHERE JOB.MAIN_ROLE=0;
```

OpenEdge 11.2 and above versions has OFFSET and FETCH clauses. Using this, the following query gets what you want:

```
SELECT EMP.FIRST, EMP.ID, JOB.TITLE FROM EMP INNER JOIN JOB ON EMP.ID = JOB.EMPID FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

More information about OFFSET and FETCH clauses can be found [here](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000043343)

Comment: #2 will probably be closer to what I'm looking for.  I'm not sure what "main role" is yet in the the DB until I get into it next.  I'm thinking it's a varchar...  So I'll need to take the top record.  Is there an equivalent in 11.1?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, this is for 1000+ records.  Some have multiple roles, some don't...

Comment: JOB.MAIN_ROLE is of type BIT. I created tables as per your examples in the question. I updated the answer with CREATE and INSERT statements.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no equivalent of OFFSET FETCH in OpenEdge 11.1